# Jackson deserialize different strings to the same enum constant

Tags: java, serialization, enums, jackson

Let's suppose I have an `enum Status` that looks like this.

```
public enum Status {
    SUCCESS,
    FAIL,
    RETRY,
    UNKNOWN
}
```

I am receiving `status` property from a JSON that could look like following examples.

- `{"status":"success"}` // valid case, deserialize to `Status.SUCCESS`
- `{"status":"fail"}` // valid case, deserialize to `Status.FAIL`
- `{"status":"retry"}` // valid case, deserialize to `Status.RETRY`

But any other value should be deserialized to `Status.UNKNOWN`. Examples.

- `{"status":"blabla"}` // invalid case, deserialize to `Status.UNKNOWN`
- `{"status":"John"}` // invalid case, deserialize to `Status.UNKNOWN`

I know I could do it by writing a custom deserializer, but I'd try to avoid that because i have many, many enums in my program, and requiring a custom deserializer for each of them would be an overkill.

Ideally, some kind of constructor from regex that matches any string (except for the "success", "fail" and "retry").

Is there a way to do it with Jackson without writing custom deserializer?

Answer (score 2):

If all of your enums have `UNKNOWN` value, you can write one custom deserializer like this:

```
class EnumDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Enum> {

    private final Class<? extends Enum> enumType;

    public EnumDeserializer(Class<? extends Enum> enumType) {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    @Override
    public Enum deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        try {
            String stringValue = jp.getValueAsString().toUpperCase();
            return Enum.valueOf(enumType, stringValue.toUpperCase());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return Enum.valueOf(enumType, "UNKNOWN");
        }
    }
}
```

And configure your mapper to user it:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<Enum> modifyEnumDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config,
                                                         final JavaType type,
                                                         BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                         final JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {

        return new EnumDeserializer((Class<Enum<?>>) type.getRawClass());
    }
});

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Alternatively you can use jackson deserialization feature for setting default value for unknown enum properties:

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, @JsonEnumDefaultValue UNKNOWN }
...
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE);

MyEnum value = mapper.readValue("\"foo\"", MyEnum.class);
assertSame(MyEnum.UNKNOWN, value);
```

But with such approach you'll need to change all your enums to use `@JsonEnumDefaultValue` annotation for default value, plus by default it doesn't handle lowercase enum values.

Comment: Could I ask how you figure out this question? I spent two days trying to trace the source code of jackson-databind but finding nothing....

Comment: Any "simpler" solution out there? Maybe by just using annotations?